# mongodb aggregate with pre sort and limit

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have the following collection objects:

```
pictureId: <String>
groupId: <String>
...
```

I have a pretty complex aggregate that compute upload time and loggin times.
One of the API is to retrieve the `pictureId`s by some given `groupId`s.

```
[...
{
  $match: {
    $expr: { $in: ["$groupId", groupIds] }
  }
}
...]
```

This is straight-forward when I get the `groupIds` as input.
How can I execute the aggregation by getting the `groupId`s in a pagination manner?
For example, query the `pictureId` of 10 distinct groups, and then the next 10 and so on.

I could only figure it out by executing a different query before the aggregation to query distinctly the `groupId`s values and send it to the `aggregate`.

EDIT

The end result should group the `groupId` so each group display the `pictureId`s.
How can I execute the aggregation without a `groupIds` input?
So aggregate will return 5 groups at a time.

```
{
  pictureId: "1",
  groupId: "1",
  createdAt: ...,
  tags: [...],
  ...
},{
  pictureId: "2",
  groupId: "1",
  createdAt: ...,
  tags: [...],
  ...
},{
  pictureId: "3",
  groupId: "1",
  createdAt: ...,
  tags: [...],
  ...
},{
  pictureId: "4",
  groupId: "2",
  createdAt: ...,
  tags: [...],
  ...
}
```

Comment: Adding `$skip` / `$limit` answers your question?

Comment: How do I combine them? I can't just skip n docs because I need to group the `groupId` first

Comment: You can apply `$skip`, `$limit` after grouping. If `$skip:0`, `$limit: 10` it will first 10 groups... `$skip: 10`, `$limit: 10`, wil return second 10 groups, so on...

Comment: I want to `$match` before grouping, since `$group` will need to go over the whole collection

Comment: Can you post please sample data?

Comment: I have added an edit

Comment: I mean, add sample data like `{pictureId:"1", groupId:"1"}, {...}, {...}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213068/discussion-between-natdev-and-valijon).